# Is my form laid out in a table accessible?

Tags: forms, accessibility, section508, wcag

I am making a form to search for colleges based on athletic programs offered and the division of the sport. I have laid the form out in a table. The "all divisions" checkbox selects all the checkboxes for that sport.

I know screen readers have both forms and tables mode. Is my current design accessible or should I add labels for each individual checkbox and position them off-screen for visual users? This also needs to meet at least Section 508 requirements.

Current code for the tables looks like this:

```
<table>
        <tr><th scope="col" colspan="2">All Divisions</th>
            <th scope="col">Div I</th>
            <th scope="col">Div II</th>
            <th scope="col">Div III</th>
            <th scope="col">Other</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><th scope="row">Baseball</th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>                    
        <tr><th scope="row">Basketball</th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What I want to know is whether or not a screen reader is able to associate the table headings with the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is accessible. I coppyed the code into a html document and was able to read the check boxes with headers in both firefox 3.0 and Internet explorer 7 using Jaws version 10.0 as the screen reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need individual labels for each of the checkboxes, but you **may** be able to use the [`headers` attribute](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_td_headers.asp) on the table cells to accomplish the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok [using the "ID" and "Headers" attributes in tables](http://www.access-board.gov/sec508/guide/1194.22.htm) (scroll down to section).

```
<table>
    <tr><th id="all" colspan="2">All Divisions</th>
        <th id="div1">Div I</th>
        <th id="div2">Div II</th>
        <th id="div3">Div III</th>
        <th id="other">Other</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="baseball">Baseball</td>
        <td headers="baseball all"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td headers="baseball div1"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td headers="baseball div2"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td headers="baseball div3"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td headers="baseball other"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>                    
</table>
```